# How to apply jquery .on/.off and click event using a html table with a button per data row

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-on

In my List.cshtml I have a razor foreach on a model.

In the document.ready I do this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#deleteCustomer', function(e){  
                e.preventDefault();

            // Make ajax call to database and delete the custmer

            // if success delete the customer tr-tag also from the UI

});
```

When my List.cshtml foreach table is initially empty and I added during runtime 3 customers that means 3 tr-tags to the tbody-tag then it seems that for each row the click is registered. This is bad on the one side because when I click the delete button the event is fired 3 times.

When I use this code:

```
$(document).one('click', '#deleteCustomer', function(e){  
                e.preventDefault();

            // Make ajax call to database and delete the custmer

            // if success delete the customer tr-tag also from the UI

});
```

Then I can only delete a customer one time. When I hit the other delete buttons for customer1 and customer2 the event is not fired.

Using the .click is not enough because my elements are added at runtime.

```
    $('#deleteCustomer').click(function (e) {
```

How can I subscribe to a html table where each row has a delete button so I have not fired multiple events for one click or one event and the other buttons do not work then anymore?

1.) What is the correct subscribing/unsubscribing?

2.) Should I also better use a .deleteCustomer on every button for a table row? Is this also causing a problem?

**UPDATE**

ok this is much more complex than I thought and I know the cause of the problem:

I have a tree with nodes. Each tree node shows a customer table with its rows + each a button.

When I click different nodes  like node1 the customers1 are displayed in the #customersDiv
When I click another node2 to shows customers2 are displayed also in the #customersDiv

that means I have 2 tables laid over the other. And when I add at runtime customers for Node1 and Node2 there are too many clicks registered... That means before I enter the customers VIEW I need to unsubscribe all existing subscriptions to the click event RIGHT?

OK I just found out when I reload the same node and I create a new customer and after delete it the event is fired multiple times.

I tried to do this after document.ready:

```
  $(document).off('click', '.deleteTeststep',function() {

            });
```

So everytime I would click a node all the previous suscriptions are deleted... but that did not help :/

Comment: *" it seems that for each row the click is registered"* that is incorrect. Only one click event is registered, on the `document`. your first attempt is correct, other than the fact that you are using duplicate id's (but even that shouldn't have affected the outcome)

Comment: but the event is fired 3 times Kevin!? Is is a problem of the id isntead of class?

Comment: If the event is fired three times, that means you are binding the event three times. Move your javascript out of your asp code. It belongs in an external js file that gets included in the head or before the closing body tag.

Comment: For the record, your original code works: http://jsfiddle.net/Gdeej/ when only ran once.

Comment: @Pascal: I assumed there could be some obscure behavior on jquery library when using `on` + id selector matching multiple elements on current or previous jquery version. Since this was not the case, the only option is, as Kevin B already said, that you're registering the event multiple times

Comment: @KevinB THANKS! I moved out the whole JS code in an own .JS file so it got loaded only ONCE at startup of my app. Not everytime I click a node and the list.cshtml with the JS is loaded! Thanks again a bunch! I hate clientside with mvc razor. BETTER is only client side and just get JSON from api service...

Comment: I'll add that as an answer so that this question can be "solved"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are executing the event binding on each iteration of your asp loop. You should instead move that javascript to an external .js file and include it either in the `<head></head>` section or before the closing `</body>` tag of your page. This will cause the js to only be executed once, that way it will only execute once per click.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
<div class='delete'>entry 1<button>delete</button></div>
<div class='delete'>entry 2<button>delete</button></div>

$(document).on('click', 'button', function () { 
    console.log('... do some work ...');
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3H4vr/)

Comment: Did not help. My scenario is more complex. Please read my update :)

Comment: You should create a JSFiddle which demonstrates your scenario.

Comment: Really I can not do that because the problem is too complex... that would mean recreate my sample demo for jsfiddle...